# vim - What's the best way to set statusline color to change, based on mode

Tags: vim

I've tried to improve my vim experience trying to have the vim statusline color to change everytime the mode changes.

I've triend this: (found [here](https://gabri.me/blog/diy-vim-statusline/))

```
    "Automatically change the statusline color depending on mode
function! ChangeStatuslineColor()
  if (mode() =~# '\v(n|no)')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=008'
  elseif (mode() =~# '\v(v|V)' || g:currentmode[mode()] ==# 'V·Block' || get(g:currentmode, mode(), '') ==# 't')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=005'
  elseif (mode() ==# 'i')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=004'
  else
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=006'
  endif

  return ''
endfunction
```

...and include:

```
set statusline+=%{ChangeStatuslineColor()}
```

But there's an issue, if you switch to insert mode and then press Esc to come back to normal mode, it doesn't change back the color. It'll change back the color only when you manually enter a different mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry for necroposting, but I think I found a way better solution for this task. 
Set up desired colors like this

```
hi NormalColor guifg=Black guibg=Green ctermbg=46 ctermfg=0
hi InsertColor guifg=Black guibg=Cyan ctermbg=51 ctermfg=0
hi ReplaceColor guifg=Black guibg=maroon1 ctermbg=165 ctermfg=0
hi VisualColor guifg=Black guibg=Orange ctermbg=202 ctermfg=0
```

Now add to statusline

```
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(mode()=='n')?'\ \ NORMAL\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#InsertColor#%{(mode()=='i')?'\ \ INSERT\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(mode()=='R')?'\ \ REPLACE\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(mode()=='v')?'\ \ VISUAL\ ':''}
```

It works perfect, doesn't need any workarounds for visual mode and doesn't require additional cursor movements to trigger color change.

Comment: So simple, I love it! If you add a `set statusline=` at the start, you'll be able to `source` your vimrc file over and over without it duplicating the style.

Comment: (ps.: for beginners, add `set laststatus=2` on top of the code to actually set the statusline to 'always visible'.

Comment: How can I get more info about this? I want to set colors also for `Command` mode, `Visual Block` mode, etc. But `hi CommandColor` is not working.

Comment: @AndrejaMilosavljevic You just specify the color, i.e.: `hi CommandColor ctermbg=23 ctermfg=32` and then you can use it as you want. CommandColor in this example is just some variable name and you can use any if you wish

Comment: @wasd Needed a few days to understand that was a variable, thanks man

Answer (score 4):

I found that the below approach was the best for me. It gives me colors for all different modes, not just insert, replace, visual and normal.

```
function! GitBranch()
  return system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'")
endfunction

function! StatuslineGit()
  let l:branchname = GitBranch()
  return strlen(l:branchname) > 0?'  '.l:branchname.' ':''
endfunction

let g:currentmode={
      \ 'n'  : 'n',
      \ 'v'  : 'v',
      \ 'V'  : 'vl',
      \ '' : 'vb',
      \ 'i'  : 'i',
      \ 'R'  : 'r',
      \ 'Rv' : 'rv',
      \ 'c'  : 'c',
      \ 't'  : 'f',
      \}

hi NormalColor ctermbg=black ctermfg=white
hi InsertColor ctermbg=darkgreen ctermfg=black
hi ReplaceColor ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=black
hi VisualColor  ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=black


set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#InsertColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='i')?'\ \ insert\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='r')?'\ \ replace\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='rv')?'\ \ v-replace\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='v')?'\ \ visual\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vl')?'\ \ v-line\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vb')?'\ \ v-block\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='c')?'\ \ command\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='f')?'\ \ finder\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#PmenuSel#
set statusline+=%{StatuslineGit()}
set statusline+=%#Statusline#
set statusline+=\ %f
set statusline+=%m
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%#StatusLineNc#
set statusline+=\ %y
set statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}
set statusline+=\ %p%%
set statusline+=\ %l:%c
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for adding this. I tried to copy/paste this code into a empty .vimrc on a fresh new vim installation on a vm, in order to test it and qualify the answer and it seems that nothing happened. No color is changed on status line. Please consider try it out and refactor the answer in order to help other people. Please consider adding `set laststatus=2` to the top of the code as well to help beginners too.

Comment: @rossijonas sorry for late answer. I have updated my answer with configuration that should now work out of the box. The thing not working previously was that termguicolors was not set. Instead of setting that the answer is not using cterm colors instead.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try this vim plugin [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). It can automatically change statusline color as mode changing based on which colortheme you set.

Comment: Thank you, I already know that there are some plugins that make it work, but I'm actually looking for understanding how to manually set up. Understanding the vim script behavior on status line..

Answer (score 1):

I like to have two vim configs, one which uses plugins and another which only has a vimrc. To do this without plugin like airline i normally use this snippet from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_statusline_color_to_show_insert_or_normal_mode

```
function! InsertStatuslineColor(mode)
  if a:mode == 'i'
    hi statusline guibg=magenta
  elseif a:mode == 'r'
    hi statusline guibg=blue
  else
    hi statusline guibg=red
  endif
endfunction

au InsertEnter * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertChange * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertLeave * hi statusline guibg=green

" default the statusline to
```

green when entering Vim
hi statusline guibg=green

As stated on the wiki:

> The following small piece changes the color of the statusline when you
>   enter insert mode, and when you leave insert mode. There are no
>   mapping keys or new commands to remember, it works totally
>   automatically.

Of course if you don't like the colors chosen you can just alter these bits:

> guibg=magenta

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: I was recently reviewing another answer posted this year, and I tried out to copy/paste the answer into a clean .vimrc on a fresh new vim installation on a VM, and it didn't work.
Please consider try it out and refactor the answer in order to help other people. Please consider adding `set laststatus=2` to the top of the code as well to help beginners too.

Comment: @rossijonas, hey thanks for testing it out, could you let me know what was wrong? It seems to be working fine for me on a clean env.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what is missing since I didn't took a time to actually debug. I just tried out again, this time I created a new user on my fedora 33 (vim8.2), opened up a new .vimrc file, added `set laststatus=2` and pasted the code above. Save and restart vim, no color changin while switching modes. Looking the the code snippet and the link that it reffered to, it seems that it miss the last lines from the code snippet present on vim.wikia

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question was asked long time ago and you probably got what you'd want but anyway I will post my solution which in my opinion is good enough to share it here.

```
hi StatusLine           ctermfg=253         ctermbg=233         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineNormal     ctermfg=251         ctermbg=26          cterm=bold
hi StatusLineInsert     ctermfg=251         ctermbg=22          cterm=bold
hi StatusLineReplace    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=88          cterm=bold
hi StatusLineVisual     ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineVisualL    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineVisualB    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineCommand    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=26          cterm=bold
hi StatusLineSelect     ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineSelectL    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineSelectB    ctermfg=251         ctermbg=130         cterm=bold
hi StatusLineTerminal   ctermfg=251         ctermbg=22          cterm=bold

let s:statusline_modes_dict = {
    \ 'n' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'NORMAL',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineNormal'
    \ },
    \ 'i' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'INSERT',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineInsert'
    \ },
    \ 'R' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'REPLACE',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineReplace'
    \ },
    \ 'v' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'VISUAL',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineVisual'
    \ },
    \ 'V' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'V-LINE',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineVisualL'
    \ },
    \ "\<C-v>" : {
        \ 'text'        : 'V-BLOCK',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineVisualB'
    \ },
    \ 'c' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'COMMAND',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineCommand'
    \ },
    \ 's' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'SELECT',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineSelect'
    \ },
    \ 'S' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'S-LINE',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineSelectL'
    \ },
    \ "\<C-s>" : {
        \ 'text'        : 'S-BLOCK',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineSelectB'
    \ },
    \ 't' : {
        \ 'text'        : 'TERMINAL',
        \ 'color_group' : 'StatusLineTerminal'
    \ },
\ }

function Get_current_mode_text ()
    let md = mode()
    if (has_key (s:statusline_modes_dict, md))
        return s:statusline_modes_dict[md]['text']
    endif
    return md
endfunction

function Get_current_mode_color_group ()
    let md = mode()
    if (has_key (s:statusline_modes_dict, md))
        return "%#" . s:statusline_modes_dict[md]['color_group'] . "#"
    endif
    return "%#StatusLine#"
endfunction

" left
set statusline=
set statusline+=%{%Get_current_mode_color_group()%}\ 
set statusline+=%{Get_current_mode_text()}\ 
set statusline+=%#Statusline#\
```

Here `statusline_modes_dict` stores `key`s that are exactly what `mode()` returns and it has `text` to be shown in the status line and highlight group (`color_group`) that of course has to be added to colorscheme, or somewhere else.
Maybe there is possibility to merge `Get_current_mode_text()` and `Get_current_mode_color_group()` into a single function to reduce operations but I have failed to make it work in a statusline.