# Active window customized text on statusline vs statusline color based on mode of window

Tags: vim

I have the following in my `.vimrc` that displays a `Y` in the active window statusline and `X` in the inactive windows' statuslines in the event of split of the windows.

```
set laststatus=2

function MyStatusLine() abort
  let l:filename = '%f'
  let l:mod = '%m'
  let l:ell = '%l'
  let l:Ell = '%L'
  let l:Pee = '%P'
  let sl = ""
  if g:statusline_winid == win_getid(winnr())
    let sl .= "Y "
  else
    let sl .= "X "
  endif  
  return sl.l:filename.' '.l:mod.' '.l:ell.' '.l:Ell.' '.l:Pee
endfunction
  
set statusline+=%!MyStatusLine()
```

I am attempting to incorporate a method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65908148/492307) which on its own works for me. This changes the color of the status line depending on the mode in which the window is.

In trying to combine the two, i.e., to have both a `Y` displayed on the active window's statusline and `N` displayed on the inactive windows' statuslines, also have their colors change depending on the mode that they are(were) in (last), I attempted the following:

```
set laststatus=2

let g:currentmode={
  \ 'n'  : 'n',
  \ 'v'  : 'v',
  \ 'V'  : 'vl',
  \ '' : 'vb',
  \ 'i'  : 'i',
  \ 'R'  : 'r',
  \ 'Rv' : 'rv',
  \ 'c'  : 'c',
  \ 't'  : 'f',
  \}

hi NormalColor ctermbg=black ctermfg=white
hi InsertColor ctermbg=darkgreen ctermfg=black
hi ReplaceColor ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=black
hi VisualColor  ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=black

function MyStatusLine() abort
  let l:filename = '%f'
  let l:mod = '%m'
  let l:ell = '%l'
  let l:Ell = '%L'
  let l:Pee = '%P'
  let sl = ""
  if g:statusline_winid == win_getid(winnr())
    let sl .= "Y "
  else
    let sl .= "X "
  endif  
  return sl.l:filename.' '.l:mod.' '.l:ell.' '.l:Ell.' '.l:Pee
endfunction
  
set statusline+=%!MyStatusLine()
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#InsertColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='i')?'\ \ insert\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='r')?'\ \ replace\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='rv')?'\ \ v-replace\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='v')?'\ \ visual\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vl')?'\ \ v-line\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vb')?'\ \ v-block\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='c')?'\ \ command\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='f')?'\ \ finder\ ':''}
```

This, however, does not work and when the `.vimrc` is sourced, the following error message is obtained:

`E121: Undefined variable: #NormalColor#`

Is there a way to obtain both functionalities?

---

ETA: Following the suggestion provided by [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) of having to return the entire string from the function, I attempted the following:

```
set laststatus=2
function MyStatusLine() abort
  let g:currentmode={
    \ 'n'  : 'n',
    \ 'v'  : 'v',
    \ 'V'  : 'vl',
    \ '' : 'vb',
    \ 'i'  : 'i',
    \ 'R'  : 'r',
    \ 'Rv' : 'rv',
    \ 'c'  : 'c',
    \ 't'  : 'f',
    \}
  hi NormalColor ctermbg=black ctermfg=white
  hi InsertColor ctermbg=darkgreen ctermfg=black
  hi ReplaceColor ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=black
  hi VisualColor  ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=black
  let l:filename = '%f'
  let l:mod = '%m'
  let l:ell = '%l'
  let l:Ell = '%L'
  let l:Pee = '%P'
  let sl = ""
  if g:statusline_winid == win_getid(winnr())
    let sl .= "Y "
  else
    let sl .= "X "
  endif  
  let l:normcol=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
  let l:insert=%#InsertColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='i')?'\ \ insert\ ':''}
  let l:replace=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='r')?'\ \ replace\ ':''}
  let l:vreplace=%#ReplaceColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='rv')?'\ \ v-replace\ ':''}
  let l:visual=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='v')?'\ \ visual\ ':''}
  let l:v-line=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vl')?'\ \ v-line\ ':''}
  let l:v-block=%#VisualColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='vb')?'\ \ v-block\ ':''}
  let l:command=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='c')?'\ \ command\ ':''}
  let l:finder=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='f')?'\ \ finder\ ':''}
  return sl.l:filename.' '.l:mod.' '.l:ell.' '.l:Ell.' '.l:Pee.' '.l:normcol.' '.l:insert.' '.l:replace.' '.l:vreplace.' '.l:visual.' '.l:v-line.' '.l:v-block.' '.l:command.' '.l:finder
endfunction
  
set statusline+=%!MyStatusLine()
```

This does not work too. The error obtained is:

```
Error detected while processing function MyStatusLine:
line   27:
E15: Invalid expression: %#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
set statusline+=%!MyStatusLine()
```

everything that comes after `%!` is evaluated as an expression to produce the value of the option but you are adding more things to the expression:

```
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
[...]
```

Those things are meaningless in the context of expression evaluation so the evaluation fails and your status line doesn't work.

You need to return the *full* string from `MyStatusLine()`.

--- Follow-up ---

The output of your function should be a string so all the variables you concatenate into that string should either be strings or expressions that evaluate to strings.

`%#NormalColor#%` and all the rest is junk: it is neither a string nor an expression that evaluates to a string.

Therefore, instead of:

```
let l:normcol=%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}
```

you should do something like:

```
let l:normcol = "%#NormalColor#%{(g:currentmode[mode()]=='n')?'\ \ normal\ ':''}"
```

Also, that gigantic concatenation at the end is unwieldy to say the least. I would put all those strings in a list and finish with a join. Something like:

```
return [
    \ "my first string",
    \ "my second string",
    \ ]->join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried what you suggested based on my limited understanding but this attempt was also wrong. I have updated the OP with how that went. I would be grateful for any further tips regarding how to fix it.